# Change library location

Tags: linux

I've got different versions of the Libnet library installed in different locations on the same system:

```
whereis libnet
libnet: /usr/lib/libnet.la /usr/lib/libnet.a /usr/lib/libnet.so /usr/local/lib/libnet.la /usr/local/lib/libnet.a /usr/local/lib/libnet.so /usr/include/libnet.h /usr/include/libnet /usr/man/man3/libnet.3
```

I have some problems with compiling a program that depends on these libnet libraries so I want to remove the "usr/local/...."-ones. Can you tell me how to do that, i.e, when I whereis libnet on the command line I want to not see the "/usr/local/..." references ?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have some problems with compiling a program that depends on these libnet libraries so I want to remove the `/usr/local/`-ones

It is generally not necessary to remove the library located in `/usr/local`. So don't get fooled by `whereis`. You can specify library paths where libraries should be searched first by means of the  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

In your case, you have to add `/usr/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and append the variable to the environment of your make process. This is usually done by

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
```

before starting the make process or by prefixing the related command with the parameter assignment. Usually that looks like

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib ./configure
```

---

If you really want to get rid of the library under `/usr/local` you first have to clarify a question.

How did you install the library (since it's under `/usr/local` it's likely that you did it):

- with your package manager
- by means of `make install`
- just moved the binary to the directory

Comment: I think `ld` will prefer shared libraries over static ones.

Comment: Hello! It's under /usr/local by make install .

Comment: If you still have the corresponding makefile and are lucky enough that it implements the `uninstall` target a simple `make uninstall` should remove all files that were previously installed.

Comment: thans but I solved it another way. In /usr/local I installed the libraries and includes that are the correct version (the program I compiled searches for them there) by ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && and the bad files were overwitten. Compiling works now.